# Accessibility Error: Controls and media elements should have labels

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility

I am trying to create a button with the right chevron as shown below:

```
<button
  id='nextButton' 
  disabled={someCondition}
  onClick={() => {handlePageNumberChange(pageNumber + 1);}}
  className='fs-next btn btn-default'
>
  <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'/>
</button>
```

Everything on the UI is fine.

But getting an error when running accessibility testing.

Error:

> Error: AX_TEXT_01 (Controls and media elements should have labels) failed on the following elements (1 - 2 of 2):
>          #nextButton
>          #nextButton
>          See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools/wiki/Audit-Rules#ax_text_01 for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure that your button has a label and an attribute `aria-labelledby` indicating which element is the label.

You could use the `span` as label for your `button`:

```
<button
  id='nextButton' 
  disabled={someCondition}
  onClick={() => {handlePageNumberChange(pageNumber + 1);}}
  className='fs-next btn btn-default'
  aria-labelledby="next_label"
>
  <span
    id="next_label"
    className='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'
  />
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you @tholle for the help.

Comment: Minor correction, a button doesn't have to have a "label" but it *does* have to have an "accessible name". The accessible name typically comes from the label of a button, if it has one, or it can come from a text element that is a child of the button, or it can come from an `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby` attribute. There is an order of precedence on how the accessible name is calculated.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2. The solution by @Tholle is a good start but the `<span>` still doesn't have any text to use as the accessible name, unless the class has a `:before` `content`